# Import data from csv into a database table

Tags: sql, database, exasolution

I'm using Exasol database and want to insert data from a `.csv` file into a database table.

Here is the script

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT= 'DD-MM-YYYY';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_TIMESTAMP_FORMAT = 'DD-MM-YYYY HH24:MI:SS.FF3';
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_LANGUAGE='ENG';
TRUNCATE TABLE &1..&2;
DEFINE fileDir = './Input/';
IMPORT INTO &1..&2 FROM LOCAL CSV FILE '&fileDir&3'
ENCODING = 'ISO-8859-15'
--ROW SEPARATOR = 'CRLF'
COLUMN SEPARATOR = '|'
--COLUMN DELIMITER = ''
SKIP = 0
REJECT LIMIT 0;
commit;
```

Here is the data

```
Product | Base product | code | Product Name
44139   | 4413         | 4413 | Mobile
```

Error

> Error: [42636] ETL-3050: [Column=0 Row=0] [Transformation of value='??Product failed - invalid character value for cast; Value: '??] (Session: 1595916477624115890) while executing 'IMPORT INTO TEST.PRODUCTS FROM CSV AT 'http://19.0.0.11:00000' FILE '07hgbjhed-jhkn-4178-92f3-jhasdkgasdsgdh6556' ENCODING = 'ISO-8859-15' COLUMN SEPARATOR = '|' SKIP = 0 REJECT LIMIT 0;'

May I know please what's the issue ? How can I fix this ?

Comment: Does it break with just one row of data? Could you try wit the row separator and `SKIP == 1` to avoid the first line? If you are on linux use LF as row separator

Comment: @mucio , It’s just a sample data but actual data is having more than one record...! But it fails as I’ve mentioned....! Secondly am running on Windows...!

Comment: does it fail also with the `skip = 1`?

Comment: @mucio Yes ....It does....!

Comment: your final table contains only 4 columns? This `&1..&2` maybe should be `&1.&2`, could you try it?

Comment: @mucio, &1..&2 is correct..That am sure..!  Yes my final table contains 4 columns only..!

Comment: I'm not familiar with the `..` syntax in SQL, but at this point I would try to reduce the number of rows in the imported file to identify the rows causing the problem

Comment: @mucio ...thanks for your time ....! I got the fix....Issue was with file’s encoding....!

Comment: Happy you solved it and thanks for letting me know